# Installing Python plugin with WebStorm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, webstorm

Is there a way to install the Python plugin on WebStorm?

Some StackOverflow posts say to go to project settings (or project structure), then go to "modules", but I think that is just for IntelliJ and not specifically WebStorm, as I can't seem to find it.

I also downloaded https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python, but when I try to "Install plugin from disk" on the .zip file, it says

> plugin python is not compatible with this installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible: this plugin is not compatible with WebStorm (as WebStorm does not have other plugins/functionality that is needed for Python plugin).

List of supported IDEs is clearly written at the top of that page:

[image]

---

If you need *full Python support*, have a look at PyCharm -- JetBrains IDE for Python: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

If you just want *some syntax coloring* for Python code: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545919/783119

Also: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000634624-Python-support-for-webstorm

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run a python script in webstorm. I needed it to run the backend part of the project. I add node configuration to run configuration and edit interpreter to python path

This is the node configuration:

[image: node configuration]